# Inequality involving periodic functions and Sobolev space.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

Set $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For $\psi=u+iv$ in $H^1_T(\mathbb{R}^n)=\lbrace \psi\in H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C}):\psi(x)=\psi(x_1+T,...,x_n+T)$, I wonder if 
$$ \int_Q |\nabla u|^2\geq C\int_Q (u-1)^3  $$
Where $Q$ is $[0,T]^n$ and $C>0$ is a constant. Is there some Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality for $H^1_T$-functions? Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a $1$ on the right-hand side? What happens if $u$ is a constant (different from $1$)?

Comment: What happens if you replace $u$ by $c \, u$ (with a constant $c$) and $c \to \infty$?

Comment: I need to add a constante. True. I made an edit

Comment: So there exists a functional inequality like that?

Comment: The constant does not help with the issues I raised above...

Comment: Ok... anyway, forget my question. Do you know if there exists some Gagliardo-niremberg type inequalities for periodic $H^1$ functions?

Comment: No, I don't know.